# Preventing a website from saving the specific pages you have viewed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, pageviews

I will try to explain this the best I can. I am familiar with coding but not with HTML, jQuery or complex website building. I have been looking at the site's HTML code and files using the Firefox built in debugger.

A website uses javascript to reward new page views. When you go to a page, it saves the window.location.href (the page URL). It must save this to user specific data in some way? (I have an account, it probably saves to that somehow) Whenever you go to a page on the site it checks it against your previous data and if you haven't been to that page it rewards you.

Is there a way to prevent it from saving a page so that a visit to a page will always be counted as a new page view? If you need me to explain more from the sites HTML or files I can.

Comment: please read this before asking question so that you can ask good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the page view is getting saved by javascript this could be done by

- **AJAX**. To let the page view count as a new page view you would have to manipulate the sent data. If the site does have a good server-side validation this won't work.
- **Locally saved data (Cookies, Local storage, IndexedDB...)**. To let the page view count as a new page view you would just have to clear your browser cache. I don't think it will be done that way, otherwise the system could easily be outwitted.

A better approach to save page views would be to do it completely server-side. If it is done that way, you can probably do nothing.